# How does pulse duration and shape affect the rotation of a quantum state?

Tags: quantum-spin, time, rotation, quantum-states, bloch-sphere

If I have some quantum state $|\psi>$ and I apply a pulse to this to rotate it by 90 degrees, the model would normally assume a rectangular pulse. However, realistically, the pulse will probably have a Lorentzian lineshape. The pulse duration is usually defined as the time interval where the pulse has more than half of its peak power (full width half maximum). The area of this part of the pulse is half of the total area of the pulse. Does this mean that within the pulse duration, the state would actually only rotate half of the distance and the rest of the rotation would happen in the 'tails' of the pulse?

Comment: Why would a real pulse have a Lorentzian shape rather than another shape? I am surprised by this idea, as well as the definition of pulse duration that you proposed. It is quite standard to apply pulses, both in the optical domain and the microwave domain, that are very close to rectangular - up to some finite rise / fall time. These finite rise / fall times are often much shorter than the overall duration of the pulse.

Comment: The idea was to use the worst case scenario for the pulse shape to show that even for this case, the thing I am modelling (the spin bath of a quantum dot) would still be valid.